# TypeError: 'solders.rpc.responses.GetAccountInfoResp' object is not subscriptable (Solana program)

Tags: solana, json-rpc

This is the code I am getting TypeError: 'solders.rpc.responses.GetAccountInfoResp' object is not subscriptable (Solana program).  I have tried this but it is not working.

```
import struct
from pprint import pprint as p
from solana.rpc.api import Client
from solders.pubkey import Pubkey
from solana.transaction import Transaction
from base58 import b58encode, b58decode as b58d
from base64 import b64decode as b64d
b58e = lambda x:b58encode(x).decode('ascii')
uri="http://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com"
client=Client(uri)
usdc=Pubkey.from_string("EPjFWdd5AufqSSqeM2qN1xzybapC8G4wEGGkZwyTDt1v")
ai = client.get_account_info(usdc)
p(ai)

    GetAccountInfoResp {
        context: RpcResponseContext {
            slot: 184983995,
            api_version: Some(
                "1.13.6",
            ),
        },
        value: Some(
            Account(
                Account {
                    lamports: 182698617139,
                    data.len: 82,
                    owner: TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA,
                    executable: false,
                    rent_epoch: 361,
                    data: 010000001ce359ed5a012e04fa142b9c751a1c5e87cfd0a0161b9c85ffd31b78cdfcd8f6747a419443e311000601010000002a9e5edbb53c04679098ff7b1265,
                 },
            ),
        ),
    }
    
    account_data = ai["result"]["value"]["data"][0]

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
\<ipython-input-81-790a5356e04d\> in \<module\>
\----\> 1 account_data = ai\["result"\]\["value"\]\["data"\]\[0\]

TypeError: 'solders.rpc.responses.GetAccountInfoResp' object is not subscriptable
```

it supposed the Api response must start with the following sintax

```
{
"jsonrpc": "2.0",
"result": {"context": {
"slot": 1
},
"value": {
"data":
```

Hoever I am getting this.

```
GetAccountInfoResp {
context: RpcResponseContext {
slot: 184983995,
api_version: Some(
"1.13.6",
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the error says `TypeError: 'solders.rpc.responses.GetAccountInfoResp' object is not subscriptable`, it means that it isn't a dictionary, which you can subscript as `my_instance['key']`, and instead get fields using the dot notation, like `my_instance.key`. Try:

```
    account_data = ai.value.data[0]
```

Here's a sample test accessing these fields: https://github.com/kevinheavey/solders/blob/f8a3c31dd95168ce72cf6eaf9a5a2504a258a01d/tests/test_rpc_responses.py#L157